# Escape strings to be posted via curl

Tags: shell-script, escape-characters

I am trying to make a script that takes some atom feeds and posts them to slack through the [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) via `curl`. What I have now works for simple texts, but some of them have double quotes or `&` characters in them and that seems to annoy slack API as I get an `invalid payload` error. Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rsstail -i 3 -u "http://MY_FEED_URL" -n 0 | while read line;
do
    # This is just a sample text, it should be ${line}
    data='Something "&" and something do " "';
    payload="payload={\"channel\": \"#my_channel\", \"username\": \"Bot\", \"text\": \"${data}\", \"icon_emoji\": \":ghost:\"}";
    echo ${payload};
    curl \
        -H "Accept: application/json" \
        -X POST \
        -d '${payload}' \
        https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxx
```

The output of the "echo" is:

```
payload={"channel": "#my_channel", "username": "Bot", "text": "Something "&" and something do " "", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}
```

I am not advanced in bash scripting and I need a little bit of help. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to url-encode the data, and the easiest way to do this is to get `curl` to do it for by replacing the `-d` option by `--data-urlencode`. 
Also, you need to use double quotes or the shell will not expand the variable, so we have

```
curl \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -X POST \
    --data-urlencode "${payload}" \
    https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxx
```

You can also simplify setting `payload=` by having part of the string inside single quotes, and part within double quotes, provided there is no space between
the parts, as in `'...'"..."'...'`. So, we get

```
payload='payload={"channel": "#my_channel", "username": "Bot", "text": "'"${data}"'", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}'
```

You probably need to escape the double quotes in `data`, perhaps with `\`, as they will be inside `""` in a json string.

```
data='Something \"&\" and something do \" \"'
```

If you have read your data from the input into variable `line`, you can do this replacement with bash:

```
line=${line//\"/\\\"}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and still does not work. If I remove the quotes from the string it does. How do I escape the quotes, since they are within the ${line} variable ?

Comment: In my case I had to remove the shebang.