# cURL invalid payload

Tags: curl

I'm writing a script to send a message to Slack using curl. Here's my code:

```
@echo off
@SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET topic="Fw: *** Subject: Detail|detail|more-detail|detail:000"
echo %topic%
curl.exe -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-urlencode "payload={\"channel\": \"#channelname\", \"username\": \"webhookbot\",\"text\": \"%topic\",\"icon_emoji\": \":ghost:\"}"  SLACK_WEBHOOK -k
```

Once I execute this script, I get the `invalid_payload` error along with my echo result. Can someone help me with this problem?

I have read this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279773/escape-strings-to-be-posted-via-curl?newreg=1d1adc391a6742ba85c54503f9d4cfc3), but I'm still not quite sure how to solve it.

Comment: Is this Cygwin, or WSL, or something else? `@echo off` and `curl.exe` make this look like a Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using incomming webhook.

Choose one of following:

a) remove `-H 'Content-type: application/json'` or change it to `-H 'Cotent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

```
curl.exe -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"channel\": \"#channelname\", \"username\": \"webhookbot\",\"text\": \"%topic\",\"icon_emoji\": \":ghost:\"}" SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL
```

b) keep **content-type** as it is, but change `--data-urlencode` to `-d` and remove `payload=` from the data

```
curl.exe -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"channel\": \"#channelname\", \"username\": \"webhookbot\",\"text\": \"%topic\",\"icon_emoji\": \":ghost:\"}" SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL
```

---

But if you use Slack API (for example /chat.postMessage):

1) you need to authorize with a token - add curl option `-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE"`

2) don't use `--data-urlencode`, but `-d`

from docs: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

> When POSTing with application/x-www-form-urlencoded data, the optional attachments argument should contain a JSON-encoded array of attachments. Make it easy on yourself and send your entire messages as application/json instead.

3) remove the from data `payload=` from data

```
curl.exe -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE" -d "{ \"channel\": \"#channelname\", \"text\": \"message body\", \"username\": \"webhookbot\", \"icon_emoji\": \":ghost:\" }" "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"
```

Comment: You can also use slack api with application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Same rules applies.